# Get comments from Facebook-likes?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook app that has its own messaging system, but I still would like to show comments that users made in Facebook from user shares or likes.

Let's say a URL (e.g. http://myapp.com/?myId=100005235) is shared in Facebook, and people add comments to the share. Such comments (and the username) are what I'd like to retrieve.

Can I do it with the facebook-js-sdk?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The easiest way is by making an [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) call to Facebook. You *should* also be able to do this with a Graph API call, but in my testing I couldn't find a way to return the data you wanted.

In FQL, you'll need to query three different tables: `link_stat` to get the Facebook id for your URL, `comments` to get the comment information and `user` to get the name of registered users who've left a comment.

The multiquery follows, expanded for readability.

```
{
  "my_link":
     "SELECT comments_fbid, comment_count, normalized_url FROM link_stat WHERE 
        url ='http://funcook.com/receta.php?id=53' ",
   "comment":
     "SELECT object_id, fromid, time, text, username FROM comment WHERE 
        object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM #my_link)",
   "com_users":
      "SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comment)"
 }
```

You'll get a JSON object back. With a few test urls on my sites, I found that  `my_link.comment_count` does not always equal `count(comment)`. I've found cases where one of them shows zero and the other one does not.

Here it is in a script:

```
<script>
  FB.api(
    '/fql', {q:{"my_link":"SELECT comments_fbid, comment_count, normalized_url FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://funcook.com/receta.php?id=53'",
        "comment":"SELECT object_id, fromid, time, text, username FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM #my_link)",  
        "com_users": "SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comment)" }},
  function(response){
   console.log(response)
  });
</script>
```

Comment: wow! sound great! will test this up and let you know, thanks for writing

Comment: Could you please make the api call? i don't know how to enter the querys

Comment: Edited my original answer above with the call. Multiqueries have a different syntax than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Graph API reference for [comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/) and [posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). The latter says that each post has a `comments` object.

I've really never used the Graph API before, and I'm not good at writing code off the top of my head, so I can't provide you with actual code, but maybe something along the lines of this:

```
FB.api(
    '/19292868552_10150189643478553', // fetch a post by its id
    function(response) {              // callback function
        for (var comment in response["comments"]["data"]) {

            // process comment

        }
    }
);
```

Although it might make more sense to get the comments on the server side instead - depending on what makes more sense in your use case.

Comment: Please note i don't know any post id, just my page url

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - could you elaborate on that? Is that "page" as in Web page, or Facebook page?

Comment: Yes one page with content in my website. For example this page (as you see has own comments system, i would like to append the comments done vía facebook) http://funcook.com/receta.php?id=53

Comment: You're going to need to know a Facebook post ID in order to obtain comments; e.g., if you share featured articles on your site's FB page, that could work. It seems, however, that you can't obtain info about individual likes/shares due to privacy concerns.

Comment: is there a way to find out the postid based on the url?